# Summing, Lookups and multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, group-by, sum, vlookup

I'm not a native Excel user (much more of a SQL man) and I have the following scenario that is doing my head in. Mainly because I'm sure it's relatively simple, but because I'm not super-familiar with all the advanced functions of Excel.

I have a 2 sheets in question.

Sheet One has the following columns:

| SKU | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | $10 |
| 1235 | $20 |

Sheet Two has the following Columns:

| SKU | Business Unit |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | BU1 |
| 1235 | BU1 |
| 1234 | BU1 |
| 1234 | BU2 |
| 1234 | BU2 |
| 1234 | BU2 |

And I have the following Formula:

=SUMIF('Sheet1'[SKU], VLOOKUP($F$2, sheet2, 2, FALSE), 'Sheet1'[Price])

(Which admittedly is copy-pasta from the Internets and then I've tried to mash together to get it to do what I want)

What I am trying to do is grouping by Business Unit, look up the SKUs and multiply the total, based on Business Unit by the Price - so it would look like the following:

| Business Unit | Total Value |
| --- | --- |
| BU1 | $40 |
| BU2 | $30 |

And my limitations in Excel are causing my hair to fall out as I bang my head against my keyboard - as I'm sure it's relatively simple - but I'm missing something key.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2021 (office 365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ***try*** as shown in below as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=LET(_merge,DROP(HSTACK(A3:B8,XLOOKUP(A3:A8,D3:D4,E3:E4)),,1),
_uBUnit,UNIQUE(INDEX(_merge,,1)),
_tValue,BYROW(_uBUnit,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(_merge,,2)*(INDEX(_merge,,1)=x)))),
VSTACK({"Business Unit","Total Value"},HSTACK(_uBUnit,_tValue)))
```

---

**Notes:** **Break-down & Explanation Of Each.**

• **_merge** --> Returns both the tables as combined after looking the price for each **SKU** and then excludes the **SKU** from the array, only keeping the one required as output, i.e., **Business Unit** & **Price**

`XLOOKUP()` --> Looks Up On **SKU** To Return The Price.

`HSTACK()` --> Used To Combine **Both** The Arrays.

```
=HSTACK(A3:B8,XLOOKUP(A3:A8,D3:D4,E3:E4))
```

[image]

Using `DROP()` --> To Exclude The **SKU** Col.

```
DROP(HSTACK(A3:B8,XLOOKUP(A3:A8,D3:D4,E3:E4)),,1)
```

[image]

---

• **_uBUnit** --> Returns the unique value of each **Business Unit**.

```
UNIQUE(INDEX(_merge,,1))
```

[image]

---

• **_tValue** --> Returns the **Total Values** of each **Business Unit**

```
BYROW(_uBUnit,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(_merge,,2)*(INDEX(_merge,,1)=x))))
```

[image]

---

• Lastly we are packing the whole thing, within a `VSTACK()` & `HSTACK()` to get the required output.

```
VSTACK({"Business Unit","Total Value"},HSTACK(_uBUnit,_tValue))
```

[image]

---

Please suit the data ranges accordingly with your data.

---

You can also perform such tasks quite easily using Power Query as well:

To accomplish this task using Power Query please follow the steps,

[image: POWER_QUERY_SOLUTION]

---

• Select some cell in your Data Table,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the PQ Editor opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the 2 Tables Names,

• Paste the **M Code** below in place of what you see.

• And refer the notes

---

```
let
    //Source Table -- SKUtbl
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SKUtbl"]}[Content],
    DataTypeSourceOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne,{{"SKU", Int64.Type}, {"Business Unit", type text}}),

    //Source Table -- Pricetbl
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Pricetbl"]}[Content],
    DataTypeSourceTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTwo,{{"SKU", Int64.Type}, {"Price", Int64.Type}}),

    //Merging Both Tables
    MergeTables = Table.NestedJoin(DataTypeSourceOne, {"SKU"}, DataTypeSourceTwo, {"SKU"}, "Pricetbl", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTables, "Pricetbl", {"Price"}, {"Price"}),
    
    //Removing the SKU Column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Expanded,{"SKU"}),
    
    //Grouping By Business Unit
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Business Unit"}, {{"Total Value", each List.Sum([Price]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

• Change the Table name as **BusinessUnittbl** before importing it back into Excel.

• When importing, you can either select **Existing Sheet** with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on **NewSheet**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've got a bit of experience with PowerQuery, so I feel very silly I didn't think of that (have used it with PowerBI) - however eventually got your query to work - the breakdown and step-by-step detail as to how the whole thing worked was super helpful for my troubleshooting it when it wasn't working (Had to re-arrange columns, delete unused columns, remove blank values and all sorts of other fun and games) - eventually got the output I needed - thanks heaps.

Comment: @TheDemonLord glad to know that, sounds really good, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to achieve this. If you have Office 365, then you can try following. I have set it up on one sheet as below.

[image]

Formula in Blue Cell G2 is

`=UNIQUE($B$2:$B$7,FALSE)`

Formula in Gold Cell H2 is

`=SUM(LOOKUP(FILTER($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7=$G2),$D$2:$D$3,$E$2:$E$3))`

You will have to adopt this to suit your sheet/data structure.